# Talking about ratio - What is the meaning of 1 to 9 of X?

Tags: grammar, expressions

This is a ratio related question.
I read in a book that "1 to 9 of water".

Does that mean that water should be nine parts?

Comment: What's the full sentence containing "1 to 9 of water"?

Comment: spirit at the ratio of 1 to 9 of water to avoid the damage

Comment: 1 part spirit to 9 parts water. For every 1 millilitre of spirit add 9 millilitres of water.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you share me different sentence with to .. of .. This usage is new for me

Comment: It's very unusual; I'd not adopt it, and move on quickly. '... diluted at the rate of 1cc to 9 cc water' (or 'in the ratio of') (and formatting doesn't easily allow the proper cm _cubed_ here) is standard.

Comment: I think it's entirely a matter of pragmatics whether the solution is 90% water or 10% water, given the text as presented here.

Answer (score 2):

Using parts for a formula is another way of expressing percentages, but often makes the final product easier to prepare. Divide the number of parts of any one ingredient by  the *total* number of parts to get its percentage. Examples for liquids:

> 1 Part **X** to 9 parts water = (1:9)= 1/10 = The final product is 10% X.
>
> 2 Parts ingredient X, 1 Part Y, and 5 parts **Z** = (2:1:5) = 5/8 = The final product is 62.5% Z.

In this case the percentages are by volume.

You can use any convenient measure as your "part": a drop, a teaspoon, a glass, a gallon jug—almost any conveniently sized vessel. *You do not need to know the exact volume of your measure.* The only thing that changes is the amount of product you wind up with. It will obviously be TP x M in size, where TP is the total number of parts and M is the measure you use for 1 part.

Comment: Far more maths than English.